# How to Create an Image Upload Box for Custom Posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, images, metabox, uploads

Is it possible to have an image upload box in a Custom Post Type?

I would like the user to be able to upload specific images just for the CPT.

Comment: Im developing a Plugin to do something like it, but my short answer is: it's not a easy task if you are trying to achieve the same upload form as in the Light Box.

But you can always use a link to the LightBox uploader, and the retrieve the URL using JavaScript. I have this code right here, I can post it as an Answer, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it programmatically and it probably can be built with some of the ***Related*** Questions listed here on the right of the page.

But, IMO, this is faster and easier to do with a plugin.

#### **[Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)**

Create an image field and associate it with your Custom Post Type.
[image]

That results in:
[image]

---

#### Another good plugin capable of doing the same

**[Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/)**
A nice feature is the "Repeatable Field", which is a premium add-on in ACF.
*Reference Q&A: [Creating Photo Gallery System with Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57480/12615)*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just use the built in 'featured image' option in WP:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-post-thumbnail-featured-image-to-show-up-for-custom-post-types

If you need more than 1 image you'll have to go the metabox route.

Comment: A link is considered a poor answer, expand on the fix found on the page.  Even if it's just a quick summary with some code examples.