# Creating Photo Gallery System with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'm creating a movie blog using WordPress.

I have Movie and Trailer custom post types and I want to add a Photo feature for this and I want to add a relationship between this photos and Movie CPT.

What the best way to handle this? Is custom field the answer? And manually add the movie post id on the custom field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Use The Wordpress Plugin Posts 2 Posts by Scribu?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11899/how-do-i-use-the-wordpress-plugin-posts-2-posts-by-scribu)

Comment: It's not a dublicate, but it ends at the same place: "Posts 2 Posts".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Custom Fields is a good answer for that.

To make things easier there's a couple of plugins that can automate the process and create a nice interface for that.

One is [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), but its Repeatable Field is a premium add-on, so I'll show how to do it with another one.

#### [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/screenshots/)

This plugin also manages Custom Post Types, but, if you already created yours, they'll appear as "externally created".

Anyway, it also handles Custom Fields and you can assign them to any CPTs.

Bellow, a snapshot of a *Gallery* CPT that has only the Title enabled, plus one repeatable field for Images and another field for RelationShip <sup>(this can be any post type: post, page, cpt, attachment)</sup>.

[image]

<sup>*You'll have to read the [plugin documentation](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_make_my_custom_field_values_show_up_in_my_templates?) on how to [implement those CF's](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/wiki/get_custom_field) with your Theme code.*</sup>

Sample code on how to retrieve the repeatable image field named `gallery_img:to_array`:

```
$the_imgs = get_custom_field('gallery_img:to_array');
foreach( $the_imgs as $img )
{
    list( $url, $width, $height ) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img, 'thumbnail' );
    echo '<img src="' . $url . '" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"><br />'; 
}
```

Comment: will this also give a url for each photo?

Comment: @wpleet : Answer updated with sample code and plugin documentation links.