# Gallery backend only

Tags: gallery

I'm using Wordpress to power the blog section of my website, and also my event timeline (using custom post type admin area).

I'm looking to add the option to create image galleries, and include them in posts using a custom tag. I would like to handle the entire front end integration myself, just using the db data and files uploaded by a gallery plugin.

Are there any good back end only solutions for creating galleries or should I just roll my own?

Answer (score -1):

I used to rely on image gallery plugins, like PhotoQ -which no longer exists- or NextGen.
For one, a plugin may die and leave a migration problem, or it may be well maintained but require too much of custom coding.
Nowadays I try to keep it within WordPress attachment post type. A plugin may handle it but changing plugins is feasible.

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) is being actively maintained and can handle the task with ease. But the Repeater field is a *premium add-on*. And if you go premium, then it's better to use the **Gallery** add-on.

Another plugin option is [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/), which also handles Custom Post Types and the repeater field is built-in.
You can find a complete example on how to make a post gallery with CCTM here: [Creating Photo Gallery System with Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57480/12615).

If you want to make your own plugin, then see:

- [This gist](https://gist.github.com/4254924) is an example on how to program a repeatable uploader field. <sup>Based in [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13646200/1287812)</sup>. But as the original, it lacks drag and drop ordering.
- And [this other gist](https://gist.github.com/2057532) to see how to implement the drag and drop feature.